# SQL Server 2008 R2 Calculated Field Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a calculated field in one of my database tables, but I keep getting the error

> Error Validating the formula for
>   column FullName

I am not trying to incorporate other calculated fields so this *should* work.

I'm using SSMS 2008 R2 with a SS2005 back end.

So in the formula field I've tried:

```
Trim([dbo].[Contact].[FirstName] + ' ' + [dbo].[Contact].[LastName])
```

and

```
Trim([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName])
```

Not sure what the problem is.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

~DJ

Comment: @Denis: I assume he means SSMS 2008 R2.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rtrim(ltrim([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, got Visual Studio 2010 on the brain, clearly given that I forgot Trim _wasn't_ a keyword.  2008 R2 took the formula, which is fantastic, thank you!  I can see FullName as a field now, but when I select * from Contact, this field doesn't show.  Is there more to computed fields that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Nevermind.  We have three database versions here.  That one query window was pointing to a different database.  All is well, thanks again Denis